# Laravel Broadcasting toOthers

Tags: laravel, broadcasting

I try to use toOhers() method in broadcasting. In documentation write for this need socketId and I use this in bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
let socketId = Echo.socketId();

window.Echo = new Echo({
    headers: {
        'X-Socket-ID' : socketId,
    },
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: false,
});
```

and blade file

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script>
Echo.channel('private-orders-auth')
.listen('OrderStatusUpdateAuth', (e) => {
console.log(e);
});
</script>
```

But this error come
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/grJ5V.png

```
TypeError: laravel_echo__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.socketId is not a function
```

How I can fix it? Thank for the answers!

In general, where I can find an example code for toOrhers method for broadcasting?

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis? ```let socketId = Echo.socketId;```

Comment: not coming error but toOthers not worked. How I use this method in broadcasting. I cannot understand.